# How to link libraries in Qt project?

Tags: c++, qt, dll, linker, undefined-reference

I'm trying to add parts of `directshow` example from [libirimager](http://documentation.evocortex.com/libirimager2/html/index.html) library to my own Qt project. I can't link `IRImager` class. It has only header IRImager.h in `sdk` directory. In my `main.cpp` I just added `IRImager` class just like in `directshow` example:

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>

#include "thermovision_control_suite.h"
#include <QApplication>

// IR Imager imager interfaces
#include "IRImager.h"

evo::IRImager _imager;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    ThermovisionControlSuite w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Here is the output:

```
error: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN3evo8IRImagerD1Ev'
error: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN3evo8IRImagerC1Ev'
```

In my `thermovision_control_suite.pro` file I added this lines:

```
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/sdk
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/sdk

LIBS += $$PWD/sdk/x64/libirextras.dll \
        $$PWD/sdk/x64/libirextrasd.dll \
        $$PWD/sdk/x64/libirimager.dll \
        $$PWD/sdk/x64/libirimagerd.dll
```

It seems like `sdk` contains all needed for `directshow` example and it builds from source in Visual Studio project without any problems. Something is missing in my Qt project. Please help me to understand what is wrong.

Comment: Linking both the plain and `d`-suffixed version of DLLs is almost certainly wrong. Furthermore, you are expected to use the same compiler (family) that was used to produce those DLLs. What does `dumpbin.exe` have to say about one of those DLLs?

Comment: [dependents of libirimager.dll](https://pastebin.com/ypBMHU5N)

Comment: I meant `dumpbin /symbols`.

Comment: It shows only file type: dll, [symbols of libirextras.dll](https://pastebin.com/GH26KL0N)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an alternative solution. You can use the extension in Visual Studio to configure work with Qt: https://musescore.org/en/handbook/developers-handbook/compilation/compile-instructions-windows-visual-studio

Answer (score 0):

The documentation you linked contains the following line:

> Furthermore it is required to install the Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2013

Together with the DirectShow example, this leads me to conclude that you need to compile your application with Visual Studio, not a GCC derivate such as MinGW.

Comment: The DirectShow project compiles successfully in Visual Studio 2022, and yes, the MSVC compiler is used there. I'm trying to port segments of this program into my own project in Qt. Perhaps it's worth changing the compiler within Qt itself, although I don't think that's the exact cause of the linking problem

Comment: I can't change compiler MinGW to MSVC from Kits in Qt. https://i.imgur.com/rP3Y9LA.png Yes I use old version of Qt

Comment: it very much is the cause. everything must be compiled by the same compiler

Comment: I need assistance in identifying the appropriate set of compilers to install for this Qt version and also locating the debugger. Your help in resolving this matter would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Dependency Explorer should tell you whether any of the provided dllw depend on the VS runtime dll (msvrtXXX.dll or ucrtbaseXXX.dll) and if so what version. You should then download or compile the version of Qt you want with that compiler.